# name 'Y' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been trying to get this code to run:

```
def conference_call_discount(distance, basic_charge):
if(distance >= 50):
    con_calc = basic_charge * 0.5
    return con_calc
elif(distance < 50):
    con_calc = 0
    return con_calc

con_call = str(input("Is it a conference call? "))
from call_charge_functions import conference_call_discount
conference = conference_call_discount(dist, starting_cost)
    if con_call == y: 
         print("your conference call discount is", conference)
    else:
    conference = 0
```

However I keep getting this error: 
NameError: name 'y' is not defined

I don't know what's wrong

Comment: You haven't defined `y`, therefore you get the error. Your identation is wrong btw.

Comment: `if con_call == y:` did you mean to type `"y"`?

Comment: okey now it works thank you Mooingroar :

Answer (score 2):

in this if:

```
if con_call == y:
```

You didn't set the value for y.

You should set a value for the y variable before comparing it.